# What was the material used to write the curses for the Sotah on?

Tags: sources-mekorot, safrus, sotah-secluded-woman, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

> וְ֠כָתַב אֶת־הָאָלֹ֥ת הָאֵ֛לֶּה הַכֹּהֵ֖ן בַּסֵּ֑פֶר וּמָחָ֖ה אֶל־מֵ֥י
>   הַמָּרִֽים׃ 
> The priest shall put these curses down in writing and rub
>   it off into the water of bitterness. (Bamidbar 5:23)

I want to know what material was most likely used to "write down" the prescribed writings of the Sotah on? "Be'sefer" I think translates as "in a book", but my Hebrew isn't the best. Was the material from an animal (like how a sefer Torah is made) or was it paper like from a tree?

Comment: Did they have paper from trees?

Comment: @DoubleAA, no-one had wood-pulp paper prior to 1843. I don't believe that paper had even been invented in China at the time

Comment: "Scroll" or better yet "parchment" is probably a better (contemporary English) translation of the biblical "*sefer*".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Rambam writes in [Hilchot Sotah 3:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960640/jewish/Sotah-Chapter-Three.htm)

> Afterwards, **a scroll of parchment from a kosher animal, like the
>   parchment used for a Torah scroll is brought**.

R Eliyahu Touger [explains](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960640/jewish/Sotah-Chapter-Three.htm#footnote21a960640) "the Jerusalem Talmud (Sotah 2:4) states that the parchment must be made from the hide of a kosher animal, lest the woman refuses to drink and the passage be required to be entombed. It would not be fitting for God's name to remain on parchment from a non-kosher animal."

See also [Hilchot Sotah 4:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960641/jewish/Sotah-Chapter-Four.htm) ("not to write on paper" because it is writen "ba'sefer") and [Hilchot Tefilin 1:10](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925417/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-One.htm) ("hides of [all] kosher animals, wild beasts, and fowl").

Comment: According to R Touger's explanation, why is Diftera invalid?